# My bootstrap Admin theme wont show the google charts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I'm trying to use a bootstrap theme for my ADMIN panel.
I want to show a `google chart` in one of the sections of my ADMIN Panel.
I called the `google chart's library` in my head section as described in [Google Charts Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)

    function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['First column', 'Second Column', 'Third Column','Fourth Column','Fifth Column'],
            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $con=getdb();
                    $query2 = "My query here "; //it works fine since' i have tested it in a blank html page
                        $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
                            echo "['".$row['First_column']."',".$row['Second_Column'].",".$row['Third_Column'].",".$row['Fourth_Column'].",".$row['Fifth_Column']."],";
                        }
                }
            ?>     
        ]);

        var options = {
            title : 'Transactions for Week Day',
            vAxes: [{0: {title: 'Value'}, 1: {title: 'Transaction'}}],
            hAxis: {title: 'Week Day'},
            series: {0: {type: 'bars',targetAxisIndex: 0},1: {type: 'bars',targetAxisIndex: 0},2: {type: 'line',targetAxisIndex: 1},3: {type: "line",targetAxisIndex: 1}}

        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

And i'm putting it on the body like this:

```
<div id="chart_div">
```

Evidently i'm missing something on the `bootstrap` part, because I have used the same code in a blank `HTML` page and it works fine.
Should i add something, what am i missing?

I'm very new in `bootstrap` so any help would be appreciated.

> UPDATE

The output of the console:

```
jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:63 Uncaught Error: Container is not defined
    at gvjs_nm (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:63)
    at gvjs_VK.gvjs_rp [as constructor] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:227)
    at gvjs_VK.gvjs_CK [as constructor] (jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js:972)
    at new gvjs_VK (jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js:1005)
    at drawVisualization (ui1.php:41)
    at Object.google.a.c.xc (loader.js:152)
    at Object.google.a.c.Oa (loader.js:152)
    at f (loader.js:149)
    at Object.google.l.m.kj (loader.js:229)
    at Object.google.l.m.ce (loader.js:229)
```

Comment: Did you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @ImAtWar just updated the question with the console error output

Comment: @ImAtWar also if i go to  (`jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:63` )    it throws  `Error(gvjs_uk);return a`

Comment: where is the end of container tag? `<div id="chart_div">` should be `<div id="chart_div"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd try to close all the brackets ;)

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)
```

Comment: thanks. Just added it and updated my question with the errors that are in the console